# Get bibliography sorted by year in Elsevier article?

Tags: bibliographies, sorting, elsarticle

Using this code I can not get bibliography sorted by year. It is just mixed and even not in order of appearance in the `myrefs.bib` file (which is exactly by year).

```
\documentclass[pdftex,preprint,12pt,final,5p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}

\biboptions{square}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
  ...
  \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
  \bibliography{myrefs}
\end{document}
```

How can I solve it? Google does not know anything about elsevier article.

Answer (score 2):

The style `elsarticle-num.bst` does *not* sort the entries.  So they appear in the order of mention in the text (if you have a different result, just rerun `latex`, `bibtex` and `latex`).

Actually there are not many styles that sort bibliography by year.  `<shameless plug>` Yesterday Michael Cohen, Yannis Haralambous and I released a package `multibibliography` which includes, among other things, a style `chronological.bst` that does just this `</shameless plug>`.  Should be on CTAN soon.